# Reading and writing dictionary

Tags: python

So I thought about writing a program that takes a URL address and shortens it. I want the program to be able to write every new URL and store it in a file and generate a new short one and if the user tries to shorten the same address it'll pull out of the dictionary the result the user got last time he put this address. I set the KEY to the full URL and the VALUE to the short version. I tried to do it but when I try to read it gives me this error:

**(key, val) = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

```
import random
import string
import json

#Default items
dict_url = {
    'instagramcom/rois..../':  "https:/roi.sl/2Ly8PzD",
    'instagramcom/....../':  "https://roi.sl/2YqJa12"
}
#Updated_dict will be the dict i'll be using to input and output data
updated_dict = {}
updated_dict.update(dict_url)
#writing the default items from dict_url so updated_dict will have something 
with open('UrlDB.txt', 'w') as file_write:
    file_write.write(str(updated_dict))
updated_dict.update(dict_url)

#trying to read the file
with open('UrlDB.txt', 'r') as file_read:
    for line in file_read:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        updated_dict[key] = val



while True:
    new_url = ""
    exs_url = ""
    base_form = "https:/roi.sl/"
    user_input = input("Please Enter the URL: ")
    if user_input in dict_url:
        exs_url = dict_url.get(user_input)
        print(exs_url)

        break
    else:
        rnd_comb = (random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=6))
        rnd_comb_str = ''.join(rnd_comb)
        new_url = base_form + rnd_comb_str
        new_item = {
            user_input: (3, new_url)
        }
        file_write.write(str(new_item))
        dict_url.update(new_item)
        print(new_url)
        break
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. In `(key, val) = line.split()` -- apparently `line` splits into more than 2 pieces, at least sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

> (key, val) = line.split() ValueError: too many values to unpack
>   (expected 2)

`line.split()` splits a string on characters ignoring whitespace, and `line.split(n)` splits a line on string `n`. When assigning to this tuple, it expects two elements, but is being passed more than two after the split operation.

Additionally, the data is not being saved correctly. `file_write.write(str(updated_dict))` will write it as a dictionary. If I have a dictionary with a key of `a` and value of `b`, it gets written as `{'a': 'b'}`. When read, the code splits it into characters `['{', 'a', ':', ' ', "'', ...]` which is incorrect and is no longer a dictionary; it is an array holding the characters of a dictionary which doesn't make sense.

I would recommend using the JSON serializer before writing (to ensure that all values are encoded correctly), using `json.dumps(data)` then using the deserializer when reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your line has too many parts. U need to use list for that, or filter input data

Answer (score 0):

One of your lines in the file has more than parameters, for instance, "key value extra"

I would recommend wrapping your block in try/except block and if there is an invalid line you will print it out.

For instance.

```
with open('UrlDB.txt', 'r') as file_read:
    try:
        for line in file_read:
            key, val = line.split()
            updated_dict[key] = val
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid line value:\n", line)
        raise
```